# How can I get the IPAddr of a non-default interface on a machine that is not mine in Python?

Tags: python, networking, ip-address

I am trying to lookup the (local) ipaddr for a specific non-default interface on a host that is not the one I'm running on by the name of the host and interface.

socket.gethostbyname(hostname) returns the ipaddr of the default interface, but I don't see a way to specify a non-default interface (e.g. 'ens8' on host 'otherhostname')

I've found various methods using socket or ipconfig to get non-default interface addresses for localhost, but I'm looking for an ipaddr of an interface on another host (on my local network).

socket.getaddrinfo looked like it would work, but getaddrinfo("otherhostname", None) is returning a list which still only contains the address of the default interface on otherhostname.

from socket import getaddrinfo

ip_list = getaddrinfo("otherhostname", None)
print(f"IPAddresses are: {ip_list}")

Comment: How would you know which IP addresses belong to the same host? Which interface it's on is no business of anybody's outside the local host.